# How Indexing works in MSSQL?

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing

I have one table and 2 index on this table in MSSQL.

**Table**

```
user_master
(user_id(PK),user_name,email,org_id,fname,lname)
```

**Index**

```
index1(user_name,org_id)

index2(email,org_id)
```

when i fire query like

**Query**

```
select * from user_master where email='user1@yahoo.com';
```

it use index2,but when i fire query like

```
select * from user_master where email='user1@yahoo.com' and user_name ='user1';
```

it uses index1.

can anybody tell me in second query why it use **index1** and not **index2** ?

Comment: Since neither index is covering (contains all required columns) it's probably picking the smaller index and/or then one with better selectivity.

Comment: Look at this thread [How to use index in SQL query][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545922/how-to-use-index-in-sql-query

Comment: That is easy the first query has email in where clause and so SQL Server database engine decides to use second index which has first column as `Emailid` which increases selectivity of index for the query.

Now when you execute second query where clause has both `email` and `user name` but first index has username as first column which has better selectivity